# THE allowed range

Tags: delphi-7

Can any friend help me with this error in the firebird database? "32869 is not a valid value for field 'ID'. The allowed range is -32768 to 32767"

I'm not aware of this error, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Can you show us the context in which you're receiving this error?

Comment: You defined the `ID` field as `SMALLINT` and presumably you need something bigger, like `INTEGER`, or `BIGINT`. Without context you'll have to decide which for yourself. It usually pays the read the [manual](https://www.promotic.eu/en/pmdoc/Subsystems/Db/FireBird/DataTypes.htm)